# Microsoft Graph Beta call to create a team returns bad request

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

In our code, we create a Microsoft team with a Microsoft Graph Beta call (https://graph.microsoft.com/beta). Other calls are done via Microsoft Graph (https://graph.microsoft.com/). We are using Microsoft Graph v1.14.0 NuGet package.

Up until 30 may 2019 this was working fine. After that it stopped working and returned the following error:

```
Type: Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException
Bericht: Code: BadRequest
Message: Write requests (excluding DELETE) must contain the Content-Type header declaration.
```

Nobody was working 30 may en 31 may so nothing changed on our side.

Our call:

```
var createdTeam = await graphApiServiceClient
  .Teams
  .Request()
  .AddAsync(team);
```

The variable 'team' contains an object which results in the following JSON:

```
{
    "template@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teamsTemplates('standard')",
    "owners@odata.bind": ["https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users('a guid')"],
    "displayName": "Test displayname",
    "description": "Test Description",
    "visibility": "Private"
}
```

We have logged in to the Graph Explorer, took the access token from the cookie and used that in our own code. This resulted in a successful call and the team was created.

This is a little strange because if our original access token was wrong, we would not have been able to do the other successful calls we are doing (for example; a security group is created).

We have compared the permissions of the Graph explorer user vs the user we use in our code. We found no difference. Both have the `Group.ReadWrite.All` permission.

Sometimes we are receiving another error on the same call with the same data:

**Update:** We receive the error below after upgrading to Microsoft Graph v1.50.0 and Microsoft Graph Core v1.16.0

```
Type: Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException
Bericht: Code: UnauthorizedAccess
Message: Failed to execute Templates backend request CreateTeamFromTemplateRequest. 
Request Url: https://teams.microsoft.com/fabric/templates/api/team, 
Request Method: POST, Response Status Code: Unauthorized, Response Headers: Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=2592000
X-MSEdge-Ref: Ref A: 266D45253C1B41809D27E6B7815E094E Ref B: DB3EDGE1119 Ref C: 2019-06-05T09:25:18Z
Date: Wed, 05 Jun 2019 09:25:18 GMT, 
ErrorMessage : {
   "errors":[{
     "message":"AccessToken token is not valid."
    }],
    "operationId":"2d511c3df28add419e9aa37926ccb962"
}
```

**Additional information:**

We are using the App context.

Our code to get the accesstoken:

```
var authContext = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{this.domain}");
var credential = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientCredential(ClientID, ClientSecret);
var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/", credential);

accessToken = authResult.AccessToken;
```

Failed request (with token that is now expired):

```
Method: POST,
RequestUri: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams',
Version: 1.1,
Content: System.Net.Http.StringContent,
Headers:
{
  SdkVersion: Graph-dotnet-1.14.0
  FeatureFlag: None
  FeatureFlag: RedirectHandler, RetryHandler, AuthHandler, DefaultHttpProvider
  Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache
  Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6IkFRQUJBQUFBQUFEQ29NcGpKWHJ4VHE5Vkc5dGUtN0ZYblRaYWluNkdtNWhnRnRrWEh0RlRydFhtRUM2bUZJZFI0X00wMkRoMFg5QzVIaFU0ZHhyRFE2cU1rMGVFOEFVbWtqZnZaMjFlZFZKR1NXYUY5bGdsRFNBQSIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2IiwieDV0IjoiQ3RmUUM4TGUtOE5zQzdvQzJ6UWtacGNyZk9jIiwia2lkIjoiQ3RmUUM4TGUtOE5zQzdvQzJ6UWtacGNyZk9jIn0.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.DXO3VpCj5GyULTxiCvdyV5Fv33D5QER4CQDkhfxi-0t8MGXJ7reositSt2-oNqxRwQ3iI0_R-kXsldaPtf7mR0aP2HgJeWQoy_MiTKtLU8RwW9hkgJEohjeeWku9edOn_fsLj8V1Yw4eLeXroqPLEmIWQ4ks8mG9Q1T3Q-9mixhjI7b4by7wIJgFe6DvmI7Yo9KYg4HygCPJ-FQJH8yeDGQWbyuy0pskNmj88b77k3fL_3-c-OAL74dOZ-FCcTkIq63bvg8NxKSgRWb5OMu7JK6cjfKUhPFWLTk2l8Aqq8UYXqoSQynX2ZvaJsBmARb6vLIeflwLPC4yr73afj6NtA
  Content-Type: application/json
  Content-Length: 305
}
```

Body:

```
{
    "template@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teamsTemplates('standard')",
    "owners@odata.bind": ["https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users('a guid')"],
    "displayName": "Test displayname",
    "description": "Test Description",
    "visibility": "Private"
}
```

The response is a Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException:

```
{
    Code: BadRequest
    Message: Write requests (excluding DELETE) must contain the Content-Type header declaration.
    Inner error
}
```

Responseheaders:

```
{
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    request-id: 1daa5989-7fbe-44c1-89f8-908c3adb740b
    client-request-id: 1daa5989-7fbe-44c1-89f8-908c3adb740b
    x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"West Europe","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"5","ScaleUnit":"003","RoleInstance":"AGSFE_IN_44","ADSiteName":"WEU"}}
    Duration: 5.254
    Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
    Cache-Control: private
    Date: Thu, 27 Jun 2019 07:56:27 GMT
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
   at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.<SendAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.<SendRequestAsync>d__34.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.<SendAsync>d__30`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at MOO.Apps.Office365.Backend.Repository.Office365.TeamO365Repository.<CreateAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
```

**Some more additional information:**

We get a working token (we used the returned token in our code) if we do the following call in Postman with our clientId and clientSecret.

```
Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/domain/oauth2/v2.0/token
BODY client_id=clientidguid&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default&client_secret=clientsecret&grant_type=client_credentials
```

Comment: Please help with these questions: Are using the User/ App context? How are you getting the token from code? Can you share expired token which is not working along with recent failed request/response?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT I've added the additional information you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try passing "https://graph.microsoft.com" instead of "https://graph.microsoft.com/" in *authContext.AcquireTokenAsync()*?

```
var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com", credential);
```

We are looking working on a fix but meantime please try this workaround and let us know if you are still facing the same issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We tried passing it without the slash at the end of the url a few weeks ago and it raised the same error.
Today I tried to reproduce the error to double check this, and everything seems to be working fine now (without doing any changes).
Do you have/does anyone have any idea what might have been changed in the meanwhile?

Comment: I believe the fix for this is rolled out.